# android ViewFlipper - slideshow of images with async image loading

Tags: java, android, eclipse, slideshow

I'm implementing a custom view where I use ViewFlipper which shows my custom View that consists of RelativeLayout parent and two children - ImageView and ProgressBar.
Initially I display thumbnail images in the ViewFlipper and when the particular child View is shown, I want to inintiate the full size image download for display. The problem is that in ViewFlipper I need to add all child View at the beginning (in onCreate of my Acticity). There are situations where my gallery consists of > 200 images and I do not want to initiate download of all the fullsize images because user may not navigate to all pages of the ViewFlipper at all. Is there a way to be notified in ViewFlipper that a particular view gets activated? I can hardly see it in this class.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no callback to inform you that a view gets activated; you need to implement this yourself. It's not hard: you need to subclass ViewFlipper and create a custom listener **ViewFlipperListener** with a method **public void onViewFlip(ViewFlipper view, View newView)**.

Then override the **ShowNext()** and **ShowPrevious()** methods inherited from ViewAnimatior. In these methods, call their super counterparts and then call the listener's onViewFlip callback passing in the new view (which you can get with **getCurrentView()**).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking of it. Since no other hints are there, I have to accept this one with an addition that i will also have to detect that the 1st view is activated

Comment: @cubesoft if you did this can you post the code of it at pastebin.com ?